# Unauthorized Error: Query or Save Contact/lead in Dynamics CRM Using C#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365

I am using the following web api to query data from Dynamics CRM

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
                    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxxx@mydomain.com", "!@Demo1$#2") });
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://xxxxx.crm.dynamics.com");
                    client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);
                    string contactAltUri = client.BaseAddress + "api/data/v9.0/accounts?$select=name&$top=3";
                    HttpResponseMessage createResponseAlt1 = await client.GetAsync(contactAltUri);
```

Now in object `createResponseAlt1` I can see the following Unauthorized error. What is the right way to query and save data to Dynamics CRM? I have username, password and Ms crm subdomain url.

```
{StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  x-ms-service-request-id: 4b323404-cc13-407c-bb6d-56b61823ab84
  REQ_ID: 4b323404-cc13-407c-bb6d-56b61823ab84
  AuthActivityId: 85696c96-6803-4664-9391-d28f45d1766a
  NativeWebSession-Version: 2
  Date: Thu, 07 Mar 2019 13:42:36 GMT
  Set-Cookie: ApplicationGatewayAffinity=03da1c2a15fe28b54ffa99b7eab01d12cd9b55dfb1779b6cccce0809ec64f39a;Path=/;Domain=xxxxx.crm.dynamics.com
  Server: 
  WWW-Authenticate: Bearer authorization_uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/e20b0aa3-6ec3-4272-a76a-aaa32e0f10d6/oauth2/authorize, resource_id=https://xxxxx.crm.dynamics.com/
  Content-Length: 0
}}
```

Comment: The login account used should have security role assigned in CRM. Able to login in browser?

Comment: yes i am able to login in browser

Comment: copy the value you are getting in contactAltUti variable & paste in browser address bar, see if it works?

Comment: How about you add Rest Builder https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMRESTBuilder into your CRM organization and there try your Webapi query.

I am not sure if using Webapi is your only required way to query/update CRM.
If not can I suggest another way, using Organization Service.
Here is sample example link for Reference 
https://arunpotti.wordpress.com/2018/02/03/step-by-step-to-connect-dynamics-365-crm-online-v9-x-using-c-console-application/

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**: Register an app in Azure Active directory (AAD) to get Application Id (aka Client Id). [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/walkthrough-register-dynamics-365-app-azure-active-directory)

**Step 2**: Use the Client Id to get the authentication token using OAuth, as the CRM online needs to authenticate using AAD this is the approach we have to follow. [Read more](https://www.inogic.com/blog/2016/03/programming-using-webapi-through-c-in-dynamics-crm-2016/)

**Code sample**:

```
        static string serviceUri = "https://yourorg.crmx.dynamics.com/";
        static string redirectUrl = "https://yourorg.api.crmx.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/";

        public static string GetAuthToken()
        {

            // TODO Substitute your app registration values that can be obtained after you
            // register the app in Active Directory on the Microsoft Azure portal.
            string clientId = "3oi467rf-2336-4039-b82i-7c5b859c7be0"; // Client ID after app registration
            string userName = "xyz@youOrg.onmicrosoft.com";
            string password = "Password";
            UserCredential cred = new UserCredential(userName, password);

            // Authenticate the registered application with Azure Active Directory.
            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/common", false);
            AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireToken(serviceUri, clientId, cred);
            return result.AccessToken;
        }
        public static void RetrieveAccounts(string authToken)
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = null;
            httpClient = new HttpClient();
            //Default Request Headers needed to be added in the HttpClient Object
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-Version", "4.0");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            //Set the Authorization header with the Access Token received specifying the Credentials
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authToken);

            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(redirectUrl);
            var response = httpClient.GetAsync("accounts?$select=name").Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var accounts = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
        }
```

[Reference](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/287107)

Comment: I am doing the same thing but my response is still 401 Unauthorized. Are there any settings/permissions at instance level or at AAD app level that you did to make this work? I am following this article - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/authenticate-oauth#connect-as-an-app